# sqlite not updating record in android

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I know there is a record with id 1 in the sqlite database but for some reason it is not updating.

```
              String sql = "UPDATE "+MySQLiteHelper.TABLE_INVENTORY+ " SET "+
          MySQLiteHelper.INVENTORY_ACTIVE+" = 0 " +
          "where "+MySQLiteHelper.INVENTORY_ID + " = " + 1;
          Log.v("sql",sql);
          database.rawQuery(sql, null);
```

It is not showing any errors, any clue what may be happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `rawQuery`, but try it with [execSQL](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#execSQL%28java.lang.String%29).

Comment: ya, just figured that out like 2 seconds ago 1 hour later.